# How to use BigInteger with an array?

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger, fibonacci

I'm working on altering my Fibonacci sequencer so that the numbers after reaching ~100th term don't wrap around and become negative.
How do I use BigInteger in this code that I wrote:

```
package me.kevinossia.mystuff;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FibonacciDisplayer 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total;
    System.out.print("This is a Fibonacci sequence displayer.\nHow many numbers would you like it to display?");
    total = input.nextInt();
    long[] series = new long[total];
    series[0]=0;
    series[1]=1;

    for(int i=2;i<total;i++)
    {
        series[i]=series[i-1] + series[i-2];
    }
    for(int j=0; j<total; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(series[j] + "\n");
    }
    input.close();
}
}
```

I've searched google high and low and I can't find anything specific to my case.

Comment: UH... so use `BigInteger` instead of `long`?

Comment: Go to this link. Hope this may help you: http://www.n-e-x.co.uk/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=code:java:fibonacci

Comment: *"I've searched google high and low and I can't find anything specific to my case."*.  What did you search for?  I'm sure if you searcherd for BigInteger you would find LOTS of examples on how to use it ...

Comment: I did, just not anything for a Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure that you only want to use BigInteger then you should think of creating array of BigInteger. So like

```
BigInteger[] series = new BigInteger[total];
series[0]=BigInteger.ZERO;
series[1]=BigInteger.ONE;

and in loop do
series[i] = series[i-1].add(series[i-2])
```

See this [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add%28java.math.BigInteger%29) API

Comment: Thank you very much, except I am not familiar with ZERO and ONE. I saw them on the javadocs but it didn't say what they were, or at least I didn't see it.

Comment: @KevinOssia If you are not familiar with that, simply put BigInteger.valueOf(0L); or BigInteger.valueOf(1L) should give u the same result

Answer (score 1):

If total is also BigInteger, then

```
BigInteger total = new BigInteger("1000000000000000");
BigInteger[] series = new BigInteger[total.intValue()];
series[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
series[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
series[i] = series[i-1].add(series[i-2]);
```